# OBS alternative for server: Creating a continuous video streaming to RTMP server and beign able to manipulate it using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

What I want is to be able to create a livestream from a Ubuntu v14.04 server to a RTMP Server (like Twitch) and to be able to use NodeJS to control visual aspects (adding layers, text, images) and add different sources (video files, others livestreams, etc). Like having [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) running on a server.

What I've done/researched so far:

**FFmpeg**

With ffmpeg I can can create video files streams like that:

`ffmpeg -re -i video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -c:a aac -ab 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://example.com`

Also using the `filter_complex` I can create something near to a layer like this tutorial explains:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20mosaic%20out%20of%20several%20input%20videos

But I found the following problems:

- The streams that I create with ffmpeg only last until the video file is over, if I wanted to stream multiple video files (dynamic playlist) it would interrupt the stream between each file;
- The manipulation is very limited as far as I am concerned, I can't edit `filter_complex` once ffmpeg is executing;
- Can't display text and create animated overlays, like sliding text.

I tried to search for any cli/nodejs package that is able to create a continuos video stream and manipulate it to use as input source for ffmpeg which streams to the RTMP server.

Can someone give me more information about what I am trying to do?

I'm playing with `github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg` to see if I have a different outcome.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. There is still no alternative for OBS to manipulate video source.

Comment: Did you find any solution?